# passing arguments to click or submit function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to pass arguments to click or submit function like :

```
$("#example").click(function()
{
  var myVar = x; // refering to x as passed argument
});
```

Maybe function inside a function ?

```
function Func(){
  $("#example").click(function()
{
  var myVar = x;
});
}
```

Maybe something like calling `Func()('33');` will this pass the 33 to the click function, is it possible after all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what you want to accomplish, its hard to tell you what to do. Many times when a similar need arrises, it has to do with passing an ID to the function. There are a few ways to handle this, but lets look at one:

```
var $a  = $('a'), // Pretend we have three `a` elements
    keys = ['apple','orange','grape'];

$a.each(function(i,el){
  var val = keys[i]; // Declare a variable to this scope using `var` and set it to the value you want:
  $(this).click(function(){
     alert(val);
  });
});
```

Now, if you click the first `a` it alerts `apple`, the second `orange`, and the third `grape`. By declaring a variable in the function scope using `var` allows that particular click to know the correct value.

[**Demo of this working**](http://jsbin.com/ijica/2)

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on what "arguments" you want to pass. Much of this is often times handled with some simple attributes on the elements themselves:

```
<a rel="foo" href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<a rel="bar" href="http://stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

Which would use the `rel` attribute as the "argument." You could access it from the `$.click()`:

```
$("a").click(function(){
  switch( $(this).attr("rel") ) {
    case "foo": 
      // do x
      break;
    case "bar":
      // do y
      break;
  }
});
```

As you could imagine, this could be extended to include attributes like:

```
rel="foo,2,max"
```

Where the value of `rel` will be `.split()` within the click-method giving us an array of "arguments" to consider in our logic.

```
$("a").click(function(){
  var arguments = $(this).attr("rel").split(",");
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    alert(arguments[i]);
  }
});
```

Comment: @Jonathan Sampson thanks that is interesting, what if I wanted to pass more than one argument? 2 lets say

Comment: +1 I rarely need to pass information to the click handler that isn't contained in the element already! Also of note, are the new `data-` prefixed attributes in HTML5 for holding random data.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access parameters passed to `Func` in the click function, you can just do it:

```
function Func(x) {
  $("#example").click(function()
  {
    var myVar = x;
  });
}
```

The inner function definition builds a closure, and the local variables of the outer function are kept in the scope of that closure and can still be accessed, even if the outer function already finished.